# How to display gridview row to particular view?

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-basic-app

This is my grid :
[image]

I made a query and created a dataprovider to view in a gridview, and now I want to view each row in a particular view. How do I get all line data to send when clicking preview?

on my controller

```
    $model = new Aviso();

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {

        $seg = $model->seguradora;

        $seguradora =  SeguradoraSearch::getNomeSeg($seg);

        $query = new Query; 

        $query->select(['apolice_idapolice','nome','email', 'contacto','premio','data_final','situacao'])
              ->from('seguro')
              ->innerJoin('cliente', 'cliente_idcliente = idcliente')
              ->where(['between','data_final' ,$model->data_inicio,$model->data_final])
              ->andWhere(['situacao'=> "Pendente"])
              ->andWhere(['seguradora_idseguradora'=>$seg]);

        $dataAviso = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $query,
    ]);
               return $this->render('index',[
                  'dataProvider' => $dataAviso,'segName'=>$seguradora,

        ]);
    }
    return $this->render('create', [
        'model' => $model,
    ]);
}
```

On My index

```
<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'summary' => '',    
    'columns' => [
         ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],

        ['attribute'=>'nome',
         'label'=>  'Cliente', 
        ],
        ['attribute'=>'email',
         'label'=>  'E-mail', 
        ], 

        ['attribute'=>'apolice_idapolice',
         'label'=>  'Apolice', 
        ], 

        'contacto',
        ['attribute'=>'premio',
        'format' => ['decimal', 2],
         'label'=>  'Valor (Mts)', 
        ],              
        'data_final',
        ['attribute'=>'situacao',
         'label'=>  'Situação', 
        ], 
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn', 'template' => '{view}','header' => 'visualizar' ],

    ],
]); ?>

<?php Pjax::end(); ?>
```

I wamt to click on the icon visualizar and render on particular view.

Answer (score 1):

You could configure the ActionColumn  in proper way using template and urlCreator

assuming $model->id is you target id  for the view

```
['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn',
    'template' => '{view}',                        
     'urlCreator' => function ($action, $model, $key, $index) {
         if ($action === 'view') {
          return \yii\helpers\Url::to(['your-controller/your-action', 'id' => $model->id]); 
         }
     }
],
```

Comment: Hi Jin Lee, Thanks for your contribution, but this is not working for my case.
I've no model define for this class, if I had it was be easy. This grid comes from a Query Builder and I made a dataprovider. thats why a view button not find a model. 
In this case, I want a solution to view a row on a particular view.

Comment: @CandidoNgovo  ... the is for the the gridview action column  you must only chage you code and adapt  the sample inmy answer ...  and i'm not  Jin Lee ...